# ROS rViz does not reflect my initial pose

Tags: ros

With ROS Indigo, I am using a blank map and setting the initialpose by publishing to the initialpose topic. I expected that rViz would subscribe to this and that the initial pose in rViz would reflect it. But publishing different initial pose's does not change the initial location of my robot in rViz. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. It was a bug in the indigo branch of the fake_localization node of the example I was trying. Now it works as I expected it should.